# SQL Server procedure / transaction with global parameter?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, procedure

I'm trying to write a procedure that inserts rows of hours earlier, if procedure gets an error next time inserts 2 hours before etc. :

This code overwrites `ERROR_COUNT`. how I must to declare a variable `@error_count` that value was stored for each call ?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[errorcount]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Data DateTime
    DECLARE @error_count int 

    SET @error_count = 0

    -- if first run error_count = 0 --
    SET @Data = DATEADD(HOUR, -1 * @error_count - 1, GETDATE())

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        Select ... where Date > @Date
        IF @@ERROR <> 0
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
                set @error_count= @error_count + 1;

            END
        ELSE begin
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        set @error_count = 0 
    end
END
```

Comment: All global variables in t-sql are predefined. you can't declare a global variable, but you can save a value to a table, or a global temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

Zohar is right.  There is no such thing as a global variable in Transact SQL.  Even what used to be called global variables were always really functions, and were never user definable.  Save the value in a table as Zohar suggested.